# Problem installing mathrsfs (on mac)

Tags: packages, installing

I'm trying to install the mathrsfs font package. I followed the instructions [here](https://scholar.princeton.edu/scuellar/blog/2014/02/adding-new-packages-latex). I'm using Anki to compile LaTeX. I'm trying to load the package by typing \usepackage{mathrsfs} in the place where all the other \usepackage commands are, but when I try to compile a document (a flash card in this case, as it's Anki), even if the card does not involve a \mathrsfs command, I get the error:

```
Error executing latex.
Generated file: /var/folders/j_/c87rrmxn4sj3db6sjz9nnnjh0000gn/T/anki_temp/tmp.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./tmp.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/mathrsfs.sty)
(./tmp.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd)
kpathsea: Running mktextfm rsfs10
/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation  for rsfs10.
/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update ?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input rsfs10
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded base=mf)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf rsfs10

! I can't find file `rsfs10'.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input rsfs10
                                                  
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input rsfs10
                                                  
Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: rsfs10.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input rsfs10' failed to make rsfs10.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm rsfs10
/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation  for rsfs10.
/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update ?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input rsfs10
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded base=mf)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf rsfs10

! I can't find file `rsfs10'.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input rsfs10
                                                  
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input rsfs10
                                                  
Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: rsfs10.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input rsfs10' failed to make rsfs10.tfm.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm rsfs5
/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation  for rsfs5.
/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update ?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input rsfs5
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded base=mf)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf rsfs5

! I can't find file `rsfs5'.
<*> ...e:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input rsfs5
                                                  
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...e:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input rsfs5
                                                  
Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: rsfs5.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input rsfs5' failed to make rsfs5.tfm.

! Font U/rsfs/m/n/12=rsfs10 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found
.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.11 $\mathcal
              {O}$
! Font U/rsfs/m/n/8=rsfs10 at 8.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.11 $\mathcal
              {O}$
! Font U/rsfs/m/n/6=rsfs5 at 6.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.11 $\mathcal
              {O}$
[1] (./tmp.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on tmp.dvi (1 page, 228 bytes).
Transcript written on tmp.log.
```

I'm copying the mathrsfs.rme and mathrsfs.sty files to the folder called "base" with address:

> /usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex

When I downloaded the mathrsfs package I got a folder called jknappen that had a bunch of files in it, which seemed to correspond to other packages, but I was only interested in mathrsfs so I pulled those two files out.

When I run "which latex" on terminal I get

> /Library/TeX/texbin/latex

What can I do?

P.S. I have tried running "tlmgr install mathrsfs" but I get an error saying the remote repository is a 2020 version which isn't compatible with my 2019 LaTeX. I could try to simply update my LaTeX but I don't know if theres a foolproof way and I'm scared of botching the installation and ruining everything.

Comment: Are you so pressed for space on your machine that you can't install the full MacTeX instead of BasicTeX? This makes life a lot simpler since you basically never have to install anything. If it's not a big deal, I would just download the current full MacTeX and work from there. You  won't ruin anything since the different versions are independent of one another. Many of us have multiple years of MacTeX installed on our machines.

Comment: @AlanMunn I wasn't aware I was using a smaller version! Do I just install full MacTex, no need to uninstall anything? How will Anki know which version of LaTeX to use? Does MacTex include an app to aid in managing packages? Cause that would be amazing!

Comment: Avoid manually installing packages, especially font packages. Instead, use `tlmgr install jknapltx rsfs`. You may need to prepend `sudo`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Gives me the same result: ``tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2019) is older than remote repository (2020)''.

Comment: Then you need to upgrade to/install texlive 2020.

Comment: @JKEG Yes you can download MacTeX and it will configure everything correctly assuming Anki is configured to use `~/Library/texbin` as its path. MacTeX comes with the great GUI TeX Live Utility to manage updates.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you Alan.